# remove first li of ul in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

There is a loop whithin loop

```
<?php while ($data = mysql_fetch_array($some)) 
{?> 
  <div class="pro"> 

    <div class="right-block"> bla bla bla bla </div>

     <ul class="color">

      <?php while($bla = $bla)
       { ?>
          <li><?php echo $bla; ?></li>
       <?php } ?> 

     </ul>
   </div> 

 <?php } ?>
```

this loop show 152 products and each product have minimum 3 to 4 colors

now I want to remove first `li` of `ul` from each product

if i use like this `$(".color li:first").css("display" , "none");` this hide just first `li` of first `ul` but i want to remove first `li` from each `ul`

I tried using `next()` and functions like `.each`. I've also created a function and called it in the first while loop just above the `ul`.

Nothing works.

Could you help me please ?

Comment: How about showing us a snippet of the generated HTML instead of the PHP?

Comment: Just do `$bla = $bla;` once before the `while($bla = $bla)` loop, and the first li will not even show up. No need for jQuery here.

Comment: No need for `each` loops at all. Any answer that uses `each` for this simple problem should be cut into small pieces and recycled! Resist the urge to write bloated & slower code using `each`! :) Alternative answer added below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can match the first child of any/all jQuery searches by simply using the `first-child` selector (the clue is in the name) :)

e.g.

```
  $('ul.color li:first-child').remove();
```

### JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/yj69m/5/

This basically says: "find all `ul` elements with the class "color", then find any `li` descendants, but only match the `li` when it is a first child *of its parent*"

`:first` on the other hand says "whatever I matched before-hand, no matter how many matches just return the first element".

Answer (score 2):

use css3 selectors:

```
$('ul > li:first-child').remove();
```

see [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yj69m/2/) to see it work.

note that jquery's pseudo-selector `:first` projects a collection to its first item, while the  css selector selects all nodes that are the first child of their respective parent (in fact css3 provides the generalisation of `:nth-child(an+b)`, where `a` and `b` are integers such that iterating `n` over non-negative integers produces the index of the target elements among all children. this is not needed for your current task but might come handy at some future development stage).

thanks to @Bergi for pointing out the suitability of this explanation.

Comment: i also use this but this only remove first product li and nothing :(

Comment: [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yj69m/2/) shows that the solution does work. there must be something interfering in your expanded html.

Answer (score 1):

you can remove like this:

```
$('div.pro').each(function(){

    $(this).find('ul.colors').find('li:first').remove();

});
```

[**Fiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/yj69m/)

Comment: The second variant does NOT work! see [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yj69m/1/).

Answer (score 0):

there are so many method like eq, nth-child selectors

```
$('.colors li').eq(0).remove();
```

or

```
$('.colors li:nth-child(1)').remove();
```

Comment: i also use this but this only remove first product li
and nothing . remaining 151 products are same :(

Comment: Please explain the difference between the two snippets you presented.

Comment: in header or in loop?

Comment: Your second answer will work, but **your first answer will not** and *will only delete the first match* as eq(0) grabs only the first match from the list of all matches returned by `$('.colors li')`. An `nth-child` selector applies to each `li` matched and checks the order within its parent.

Answer (score -1):

You can try this:

```
 $(".color").find("li:first").remove();
```

Comment: it remove all li's :(